# Matrix product with linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse, matrix-rank

Given a matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, show that if the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m$ are linearly independent and $Av_1, \dots, Av_m$ also are linearly independent, then $A$ must be invertible.

Comment: I think you want $m = n$. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: If $Av_1, \dots, Av_m$ are linearly independent, then
$\lambda^1(Av_1) + \dots + \lambda^m(Av_m) = 0 \implies \lambda^1 = \dots = \lambda^m = 0$
Which we can rewrite as $A(\lambda^1v_1 + \dots + \lambda^mv_m) = 0$ But here I got stuck.

Comment: So you proved that the only collections of $\lambda$'s for which $\lambda^1 v_1 + \cdots \lambda^m v_m$  is in the kernel of $A$ is when all $\lambda$'s are zero. Since the $v$'s are a basis, this means the kernel of $A$ is only the zero vector, and hence $A$ is invertible.